# Angular2 Promise 'array' does not exist on type 'void | {}'

Tags: angular, promise, pouchdb

I'm sure this is related to many other "property does not exist on type" questions, but honestly I've tried their fixes and it's not working for me...

I'm building an app using ionic2/angular2 with pouchDB.

The pouchdb promise call is within a provider service and looks like the below

```
loadUserDocuments() {

    return new Promise(resolve => {

      this.db.query('some view', {
        include_docs: true
      }).then((result) => {

        this.myList = [];
        result.rows.map((row) => {
          if (some condition)
            this.myList.push(row);
        });

        resolve(this.myList);

      });

    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("loadUserDocuments : Error : " + error);
    });
  }
```

When I invoke the loadUserDocuments from my component as below....it works !!

```
updateHives() {    
   this.ds.loadUserDocuments().then((myList) => {
      this.listToUI = myList;    
   });
}
```

The UI gets updated and there is no problem.

The problem starts when I try to iterate through the 'myList' to separate them into separate lists...Below is the code that throws the error

```
  updateHives() {
    this.ds.loadUserDocuments().then((myList) => {

      myList.rows.map((row) => {

        if (condition 1){
          this.listOne.push(row);
        } else if (condition 2) {
          this.listTwo.push(row);
        }

      });
    });
  }
```

The 'rows' object comes up as error namely "Property 'rows' does not exist on type 'void | {}'

I even tried adding another then clause to the working piece of code, but there too, my local object become un-iteratable.

I've tried reading Nolan Lawson's https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html but I'm lost.

Please help.

Thanks,
Elvis.

Comment: `myList` is an array. So `myList.rows` doesn't exist: arrays don't have a `rows` property.

Comment: I tried a for loop over the array, but then on myList.length I get an error "Property 'length' does not exist on type 'void | {}'

Comment: This is a compilation error, right? Why don't you specify types on your variables and methods?

Comment: Apparently, it doesn't seem to be just a compilation error. I tried adding the types, the compile error went away, but I still got the runtime error. I then tried to paste the returned promise array into a local array variable, that gave me an error that a promise cannot be stored into an array element..

Comment: As written, the second version of `updateHives()` expects a different version of `loadUserDocuments()`. So are you trying to call the same version `loadUserDocuments()` or a different version?

Comment: Question, why you create a new promise instead of return db.query? db.query actually return a promise so there's no need to create a new one.